# Error trying to compile Stroustrup GUI drill (FLTK, error c2039)

Tags: c++

So far I've managed to get FLTK installed, run the demo, and run the test in appendix D of Stroustrups book successfully. The issue is that when I try to compile a quick program,

```
#include <FL/FL.h>
#include<FL/Fl_Box.h>
#include<FL/Fl_Window.h>
#include<Graph.h>
#include<Simple_window.h>
#include<Point.h>
#include<Window.h>

using namespace Graph_lib;

int main() {
    Point tl(100,100);
    Simple_window Mywindow(tl,600,400,"Canvas");
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\window.h(17): error C2039: 'Vector' : is not a member of 'std'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\window.h(17): error C2868: 'Vector' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
```

It seems that someone wrote `#define vector Vector` in one of the header files, and so `using namespace std:vector` becomes `using namespace std::Vector` which gives an error. I've tried editing the header file myself but I don't have permission and can't save any changes. What can I do to solve this problem?

EDIT:

Here is the header as requested. I didn't download it from the linked to page on his site, I downloaded it from the 1st edition landing page in the form of a zip file.

Before though, I replaced the headers with the linked to header and I get a new error:

`1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\graph.h(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fltk.h': No such file or directory`

```
//
// This is a GUI support code to the chapters 12-16 of the book
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#ifndef WINDOW_GUARD
#define WINDOW_GUARD

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include "Point.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;

namespace Graph_lib
{
    class Shape;   // "forward declare" Shape
    class Widget;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class Window : public Fl_Window { 
    public:
        // let the system pick the location:
        Window(int w, int h, const string& title);
        // top left corner in xy
        Window(Point xy, int w, int h, const string& title);    

        virtual ~Window() { }

        int x_max() const { return w; }
        int y_max() const { return h; }

        void resize(int ww, int hh) { w=ww, h=hh; size(ww,hh); }

        void set_label(const string& s) { copy_label(s.c_str()); }

        void attach(Shape& s) { shapes.push_back(&s); }
        void attach(Widget&);

        void detach(Shape& s);     // remove s from shapes 
        void detach(Widget& w);    // remove w from window (deactivates callbacks)

        void put_on_top(Shape& p); // put p on top of other shapes

    protected:
        void draw();

    private:
        vector<Shape*> shapes;     // shapes attached to window
        int w,h;                   // window size

        void init();
    };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           int gui_main(); // invoke GUI library's main event loop
    inline int x_max() { return Fl::w(); } // width of screen in pixels
    inline int y_max() { return Fl::h(); } // height of screen in pixels

} // of namespace Graph_lib

#endif // WINDOW_GUARD
```

Comment: do you need the FL includes?

Comment: Stroustrup's `"std_lib_facilities.h"` does have a `#define vector Vector` in it, and your last four headers look like [his ones](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/). It's weird that `Window.h` is in the VC include folder though, and none of his headers supplied on his website has a `using` for `std::vector`. Can you post the `Window.h` file?

Comment: @T.C. I've posted the header as you requested. I also changed the headers in my include folder to the ones you linked to and it solved that error but introduced a new one.

Comment: Ugh, I see, this is messy. He probably updated his files..."fltk.h" is [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/fltk.h), it seems.

Comment: Oh, a **["disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector"](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)**. Well that's not the only disgusting troublesome thing in that header. Maybe Bjarne can require students to only walk the narrow path that he has marked for them, but still, it's so *needlessly* problematic and giving the impression that such techniques are acceptable in some situations (they're not).